Question about permissions
I have installed Ubuntu 23.10 64 bit on a Pi5.
Most things seem OK but I wanted to have pinctrl, so I copied it from Pi4 Bookworm.
Somewhat surprisingly it worked without needing to be recompiled but every time I run it I get
Must be root

It works if I type sudo pinctrl but I am at a loss why as the permissions seem OK and I have enabled passwordless sudo for my user on both.
On Pi4 Bookworm
rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 134240 2024-04-03 03:52 /usr/bin/pinctrl*
 /usr/bin/pinctrl: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=6da72e3abee5f3fb6504e0246f88f605832395cb, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped

On Pi5 Ubuntu
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 134240 Apr 25 15:55 /usr/bin/pinctrl*
/usr/bin/pinctrl: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=6da72e3abee5f3fb6504e0246f88f605832395cb, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped

Any ideas what I am missing?

Good question... though I do wonder why you chose Ubuntu. Offhand, I've no clue as to what might be creating/causing your permission issue. I do recall reading on the GitHub repo where pinctrl is posted that it dealt directly with the kernel to do what it does. That said, IIWIYS I think I'd try building from source.

You can use strace to trace system calls made by the pinctrl command to identify any specific issues. Run the following command:
sudo strace pinctrl
